# How to put tokens read from a csv file into an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, csv, token

I am writing a program that reads from a csv file and puts the values into an array of objects. So I set up an object class that has 5 attributes . What I can't seem to get is how to put the tokenized variables into my array of objects. I did a system.out.printf that uses the getters from my object class to print out the object instances in each index but I get a null pointer. So my guess is that the tokens aren't being stored in my array of objects so how can this be done? This is what I have so far.

EDIT: This is one of the lines on my CSV file 
12345,Left-Handed Bacon Stretcher,125.95,PGH,2

EDIT: This is the stacktrace error Im getting for those asking
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 5"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Prog6.main(Prog6.java:97)

```
Part[] part = new Part[20];

String partNumber;
String description;
double price = 0.0;
String warehouseID;
int quantity = 0;

try
{
inFile = new Scanner( new File( "parts.txt" ) );
}
catch( FileNotFoundException e )
{
System.out.println( "Error: File parts.txt not found" );
}

// read file
try
{

while ( inFile.hasNext() )
{
String record = inFile.nextLine();
String[] tokens = record.split(",[ ]*");

partNumber = tokens[0];
description =  tokens[1] ;
price = Double.parseDouble( tokens[2] );
warehouseID =  tokens[3] ;
quantity = Integer.parseInt( tokens[4] );

part[num] = new Part( partNumber, description, price, warehouseID, quantity );
num++;

}
}
catch( Exception e )
{
System.out.println( "File error " + e.getMessage() );
}

// close file
inFile.close();
```

Comment: What does the .csv file look like? Is it simply comma delimited? My guess is that your `record.split(",[ ]*")` method is attempting to split on a regular expression that is never matched.

Comment: This is one line on it:12345,Left-Handed Bacon Stretcher,125.95,PGH,2

Comment: Can you please post a stacktrace for the `NullPointerException` you are getting? It should be a bunch of lines that look like this: `at Foo.bar(Foo.java:2)`

Comment: yeah I edited my post with the stacktrace. line 97 is  quantity = Integer.parseInt( tokens[4] );

Comment: There we go. The problem is that one of the lines in your .csv has a value that cannot be parsed to a Integer. Put this code above that line and post the output: `System.out.println("Token[4]: " + token[4]);`.

Comment: token can;t be resolved to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see what happen

```
try
{   
    int row=1;
    while ( inFile.hasNext() )
    {
        String record = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = record.split(",");
        if(tokens.length==5){
            partNumber = tokens[0];
            description =  tokens[1] ;
            price = Double.parseDouble( tokens[2].trim());
            warehouseID =  tokens[3] ;
            quantity = Integer.parseInt( tokens[4].trim());
            part[num] = new Part( partNumber, description, price, warehouseID, quantity );
            num++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Row "+row+" skipped (record not complete)");
        }
        row++;
    }
}
```

Also, you need to check whether `tokens[2]` and `tokens[4]` is parseable. in case its value is empty string(""), space or not a number.

Comment: you need to check whether tokens[2] and tokens[4] is parseable. in case its value is empty string(""), space or not a number.

Comment: and make sure no empty line/row in your csv file

Comment: still the same null pointer, I fixed my csv file and made sure its parseable with no spaces. So now its just back to the original problem which is getting the attributes into my array of objects.

Comment: have you tried print the array? System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens)); If you can print the array, then the problem must be in your Part class

Answer (score 0):

1. First check if your program is going inside while loop, you can either debug or add a print statement
2. If its going inside while then check the lenght of tokens
3. Also is it posisble that your file has less than 20 records ?

Also share your exception statck trace and code you using to print each object

Edit:

Instean of `System.out.println( "File error " + e.getMessage() );` in catch block write `e.printStackTrace()`

use this instead:

```
Integer.parseInt( tokens[4].trim() );
```

Comment: Its going in I can do a System.out.println(quantity); and itll print out all the values for that token and #3 isn't the problem. How do I check the length of the tokens?

Comment: if all token vakues are getting printed then no need to check the length. (you can do that by tokens.length). Whats the initial value of num you using ?

Comment: Im using 0 as the intial value.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 5"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Prog6.main(Prog6.java:97)

Comment: @user2769651 Okay, good, now what's line 97 of Prog6.java look like?

Comment: quantity = Integer.parseInt( tokens[4] );

Comment: maybe you should modified it Integer.parseInt( tokens[4].trim());

Comment: @user2769651 I've posted an answer that solves your NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one of the lines in your .csv file look like so:

```
blah,blah,blah,blah, 5
```

Notice the space there, that is what is causing the NumberFormatException. Remove this space from your .csv , try (as  Rafa El suggests) trimming the String before parsing to an Integer, or try splitting on the following regex: `" *, *"`.

Comment: Thanks! Ok so well I did that and now the only problem is left is actually getting the data from the arrays or where ever its stored. I tried using the code  System.out.println(part[2].getDescription()); to see if I could extract the description attribute from the 2nd line in my csv file and I get a null pointer exception